# Set parameters for L2 cache with Hibernate, EhCache and Wildlfy

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, ehcache

I have application which use Hibernate with EhCache as a second level cache provider. The application deployed on Wildfly 8.2. 
The second level cache configured and works as expected but I cannot figure out how to provide a separate configuration for second level cache in echache.xml configuration in a generic way. Currently my setup looks like:

Entitiy:

```java
     /**
     * The Country class
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "country")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "ENTITY_L2_CACHE")
    public class Country extends AbstractPersistentEntity {}
```

The pesistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="app_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="com.torqueits.pos.jpa.ProxyJtaPlatform"/>
            <!-- enabling L2 cache -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value ="false" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.ehcache.statistics" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the ehcache.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true" name="torqueCacheManager">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <!-- Fail safe default cache-->
    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        ...
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">        
    </defaultCache>
    <cache name="ENTITY_L2_CACHE"  
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       ...
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>        
</ehcache>
```

While I configured entities to use ENTITY_L2_CACHCE as a region for the second level cache the actual name used by hibernate is

> application.war#app_PU.ENTITY_L2_CACHE

Which is uses deployment name plus persistence unit name as a prefix for region. I don't have control over the deployment name so I cannot put 'application.war#app_PU.ENTITY_L2_CACHE' into the ehcache.xml. I'm not sure if this related to hibernate or wildfly server.

Is there any ways to configure parameters for second level cache which is not bind to specific deployment name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at

```
org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings
```

class, I found

```
'hibernate.cache.region_prefix'
```

parameter which controls prefix for the cache region. Thus, to overcome the issue, I need to configure some prefix and then use this prefix in ehCache.xml configuration file for L2 cache.

The parameter should be set in persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="com.example.app"/>
```